# Flutter - Side menu (Navigation rail, Navigation drawer)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Can anyone advise me how to design a very specific Side menu in flutter.

It has 2 states

1. Collapsed (Small but icons are visible.)
2. Expanded (Big, Icons and text)

When **collapsed** it is like a **Navigation rail**. Only icons visible.

But when **expanded**, it should behave like **Navigation drawer**. It should blur the rest of the screen, and on click outside of it it should collapse back.

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you

````
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool is_expanded = false;

  int selectedPage = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 120),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 120,
                child: BackdropFilter(
                  filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 1, sigmaY: 1),
                  child: Opacity(
                    opacity: is_expanded ? 0.3 : 1,
                    child: Listener(
                      onPointerDown: (v) {
                        if (is_expanded) {
                          is_expanded = false;
                          setState(() {});

                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(
                              content: Text('Click blocked'),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                      child: AbsorbPointer(
                        absorbing: is_expanded,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: PageHolder(selectedPage),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              AnimatedContainer(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 120),
                height: double.infinity,
                width: is_expanded ? 240 : 120,
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: const [
                        Text(
                          'Custom drawer',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() => is_expanded = !is_expanded);
                      },
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            "App",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            is_expanded ? Icons.arrow_right : Icons.arrow_left,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        selectedPage = 1;
                        is_expanded = false;
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Page 1",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        selectedPage = 2;
                        is_expanded = false;
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Page 2",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  PageHolder(selectedPage) {
    switch (selectedPage) {
      case 1:
        {
          return Page1();
        }
      case 2:
        {
          return Page2();
        }

      default:
        {
          return Page1();
        }
    }
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Text('Page 1 content',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  const SnackBar(
                    content: Text('Test click'),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Test click'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Page2> createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Text(
            'Page 2 content',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  const SnackBar(
                    content: Text('Test click'),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Test click'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow community. Please add the code that you've already tried in order to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution ^^

> include NavigationRail widget in  IntrinsicWidth widget

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

      ),
      drawer: _NavigationRailExample(),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}



class _NavigationRailExample extends StatefulWidget {

  const _NavigationRailExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  _NavigationRailExampleState createState() => _NavigationRailExampleState();
}

class _NavigationRailExampleState extends State<_NavigationRailExample> {

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  bool extended =false;


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: IntrinsicWidth(
        child: NavigationRail(
          selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
          destinations: _buildDestinations(),
          extended: extended,
          onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },

        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<NavigationRailDestination> _buildDestinations() {
    return [
      NavigationRailDestination(
        icon: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() =>
            extended = !extended);
          },
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text("App"),
              Icon(extended ? Icons.arrow_right : Icons.arrow_left)
            ],
          ),
        ),
        label: Container(width: 0,) ,
      ),
      NavigationRailDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        label: Text('Home'),
      ),
      NavigationRailDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
        label: Text('Favorites'),
      ),
      NavigationRailDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.logout),
        label: Text('Logout'),
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @i.AGUIR

That's exactly what I tried. But the drawer opens from the start of the screen, I would like to make it look like the Rail expanded (transitioned) into the drawer.

Comment: ^^ you would  add an another icon clickable into List<NavigationRailDestination> and  use IntrinsicWidth  instead